# What are the possible values for scope in Canvas LMS?

Tags: canvas-lms

I have to pass **scope** in oauth2 flow in Canvas LMS but I don't know what are the possible values to pass.
I didn't see a complete list anywhere. This is the URL but I don't what to pass in scope. Any help?

> http:///login/oauth2/auth?client_id=10000001&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://my-test-url//home/oauth2response&state=30330943-16da-4371-865f-5512b6ec671f&&scope=value_1 value_2 value_n

Answer (score 1):

The scope you can use depends on the endpoint you are using, as stated in the [documentation](https://canvas.instructure.com/doc/api/file.oauth_endpoints.html#get-login-oauth2-auth):

> [...] Canvas API scopes may be found beneath their corresponding endpoints in the "resources" documentation pages. [...]

As an example, for [creating an assignment](https://canvas.instructure.com/doc/api/assignments.html#method.assignments_api.create), the scopes which are defined are:

- `url:POST|/api/v1/courses/:course_id/assignments`

Depending on the developer keys you are using, it might be possible that you don't need a `scope` parameter during the authentication process.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am receiving invalid_scope in the error in the OAuth 2.0 flow when I do not pass any scope. I am using folloiwng APIs and how to pass them as scope.
/api/v1/courses/{courseId}
/api/v1/courses/{courseId}/folders/root
/api/v1/folders/{folderId}/files
/api/v1/folders/{folderId}/folders

Comment: @Simant - I tried mentioning the scope in the following format and it works for me, maybe you can try the same - The example format of appending scope to the URI is "scope=url:GET|/api/v1/courses/:course_id/folders"